# Sobre a tag "autômato"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

A tag [autômato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aut%c3%b4mato) não deveria ser [autômatos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aut%c3%b4matos)? Afinal, a disciplina na Ciência da Computação chama-se "Teoria dos Autômatos".

Eu acho que ela foi criada apenas recentemente [para esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25885/aut%C3%B4mato-finito-n%C3%A3o-determin%C3%ADstico-d%C3%BAvida-em-quest%C3%A3o-das-%CE%B5-transi%C3%A7%C3%B5es).

Comment: Por que usar plural? Então `algoritmo` deveria virar `algoritmos`? `banco-de-dados` deveria ser `bancos-de-dados`? Não vejo motivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Eu não propus usar um padrão de plural para todas as tags. Apenas nesse caso em específico a tag parece (em minha opinião) ficar melhor no plural porque quando o assunto é discutido no escopo da Ciência da Computação o que se tem em mente são *classes de resolvedores abstratos de problemas*. Além disso, o uso da palavra no singular (tanto em inglês como em português) tem [um significado bem mais abrangente](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B4mato).